# Paso de variables en un programa Java

Tags: java, variables

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo un problema en mi 
`public static void main(String[] args) {...` tengo una variable que dentro de este procedimiento cambia de valor esa variable necesito usarla en otra clase. Ejemplo: la variable "c" necesito ocupar en otra clase del mismo paquete

```
public class mishel {
    private static int c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a, b;
        a=8;
        b=9;
        c=a+b;
        System.out.println(c);

    }
    public void set_c(int var1){ 
        this.c=var1; 
    } 

    public int getc(){ 
        return this.c; 
    } 

}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

En mi otra clase tengo

```
public class programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mishel c1=new mishel(); 
        c1.getc(); 
        int nc=c1.getc(); 
        int d = nc;
        System.out.println(d);

    }
}
```

Pero me imprime `0`.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes! Has de mirar el tema de Scope. Depende donde inicialices una variable puedes usarlas en un contexto u otro.

Comment: esa mismo en mi pregunta donde debo inicializarla por ejemplo el valor de mi variable c=17 ese valor 17 debo utlizar en otra clase como hago?

Comment: inicializala justo despues de abrir la clase, haz la clase pública, crea un metodo getter para esa propiedad, instancia esa clase desde la clase que quieras usar ese valor y usa el metodo para que te devuelva ese valor.

Comment: actualice mi pregunta e hice lo que me dijiste pero me sigue imprimiendo 0 mi programa lo actualice en la parte de arriba

Comment: porque tienes que inicializar el valor de c en el constructor de la clase Mishel(pónla en mayusculas) o cuando la creas le asignas el valor

Comment: por que tienes dos clases Main???

Comment: @sioesi, main no son clases, son métodos, y cada uno corresponde a dos clases distintas

Comment: Pero ambas clases pueden servir de arranque de la aplicacion? Yo haria 1 clase con el metodo de arranque, que cree la instancia de objeto 2, setee los valores o los muestre...

Comment: mi programa es un poco mas grande pero me encontre con este problema y para simplificarlo lo hice de esta manera pero las dos clases necesitan el main porque hace cosas distintas. En el primera clase debo subir un archivo csv y de ahí actualizo mi numero de filas que tiene el archivo y ese numero lo utilizo en la otra clase como dije es otra cosa totalmente diferente pero me encontré con este problema y no sé como solucionarlo

Comment: @Mishel segun lo que explicas, es casi como si fueran 2 programas distintos... Por que no crear en el mismo programa las dos funcionalidad pero con un solo metodo Main? Aplicando clases te saldria mas util, trabajarian orientado a objeto y tu problema que se ve complicado, seria mas facil de solucionarlo pregunta ... 1) Cuando subes el archivo csv y actualizas el numero de filas de ese archivo, donde guardas ese valor (me refiero si lo guardas en una base de datos o algo parecido)

Answer (score 1):

No recomiendo escribir tu código en la funcion main, al principio puede parecer más fácil, pero acostumbrarse a ello es malo por que conlleva varias limitaciones (Como la necesidad de utilizar variables Static). Pero esto ahora no es relevante, vamos al tema, yo lo haría así:

```
public class MiClase {

    public int c;

    /*
     * Esto es un constructor, se le llama automaticamente cuando se crea un objeto.
     */
    public MiClase() {
        int a=8, b=9;
        c = a + b;
    }
}
```

Segunda clase:

```
public class programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creo un objeto de nombre mc y tipo MiClase.
        MiClase mc = new MiClase();

        System.out.println(mc.c);
    }
}
```

La clave aqui son estos dos comandos:

> MiClase mc = new MiClase();

Aquí lo que hacemos es crear un objeto llamado "mc" de tipo MiClase. En este caso, he creado una variable publica de tipo int llamada "c" en la clase MiClase, con lo que mc tiene esa variable.

La suma la he hecho en el constructor, pero tampoco es necesario, dejémoslo así para que sea más simple por el momento.

> mc.c

Cuando he creado el objeto "mc", dentro se ha creado la variable global "c", y para acceder a su valor (Se puede ya que es pública) se utiliza `mc.c`, en mi ejemplo lo que hago es escribirlo en pantalla, pero se puede usar como se quiera.

Si tienes alguna duda, por favor, pregunta. Estaremos encantados de ayudar.

**Actualización: Getter y Setter**:

Para evitar problemas con las variables públicas (Estas se pueden usar desde otras clases, y eso puede traer problemas si no se lleva un control en programas más complejos), se utilizan variables privadas y funciones "getter" y "setter" publicas. Básicamente, funciones que sobreescriben (guardan) o leen la variable privada. (Ya que si es privada no se puede acceder a ella (NI leer NI escribir) desde fuera de la clase.

Esto quedaría así:

```
public class MiClase {

    private int c;

    /*
     * Esto es un constructor, se le llama automaticamente cuando se crea un objeto.
     */
    public MiClase() {
        int a=8, b=9;
        c = a + b;
    }
    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(int c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: me gusta tu edit. y aunque con getter me parece mas elegante, una respuesta muy valida , +1

Comment: me sumo a @lois6b, si ocuparas get y set seria mas limpia, pero buena respuesta!

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y esta parte la he entendidio bien, gracias pero mi problema es que en la funcion main es ahi donde cambia el valor de mi variable y necesito llamar a esta vriable que ha cambiado en la funcion main de mi otra clase no se si me explico bien

Comment: Cierto, los getters y setters son más limpios, y no son complicados tampoco. Ahora mismo lo edito.

Comment: @Mishel, pero cuando creas la instancia de la clase, no se ejecuta el main asi que el valor de C no lo recoges. O lo haces en el constructor como puso Mayuso, o creas un metodo que lo calcule y lo llamas tras la instancia

Comment: @Mishel Tener 2 funciones mains es (mas o menos) lo mismo que tener dos programas distintos. La funcion main se utiliza como la primera funcion de un programa (Hablamos siempre de Java, en otros puede que sea diferente, ahora mismo nos da igual para este caso). Te recomiendo copiar mi codigo y usarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo normal es encapsular las operaciones a realizar, por ejemplo empleando un clase para realizar esa suma.

## Codigo clase Programa

Esta clase Programa es la que lleva el main para ser ejecutada directamente.

```
package paqueteDePrueba;

public class Programa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a, b, c;
        a=8;
        b=9;

        ClaseSumadora cs = new ClaseSumadora();
        c =  cs.sumar(a,b);

        System.out.println(c);

        //si necesitaras usar 'c' en alguna otra clase
        NuevaClase miNuevaClase = new NuevaClase();
        miNuevaClase.hacerOperacionConElSumatorio(c);

        //o invocar un set
        //miNuevaClase.setSumatorio(c);

        //o construir la nueva clase empleando c
        //NuevaClase miNuevaClaseConstruidaConC = new NuevaClase(c);            
    }    
}
```

## Codigo clase Sumadora

Realiza únicamente la operación de suma.

```
public class ClaseSumadora{

    //obtiene la suma 'c'
    public int sumar(int a, int b){
        return a + b; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo. El método main de la clase mishel no se está ejecutando. El método main solo se ejecutará si haces un run esa clase como aplicación java.

Al crear un objeto de tipo mishel desde la clase programa solo se ejecuta el constructor de esa clase. Como no lo has definido explicita-mente se ejecuta el constructor por defecto, que está vacío. como c es una variable primitiva su valor es igual a 0, que es el valor que te está imprimiendo.

Lo que deberías hacer es crear un constructor para la clase mishel y dentro copiar el código del método main.